# Samsung Nougat SemClipboardManager

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy

I am keep getting crashes reported on Fabric. All crashes are coming from Samsung Galaxy S6 running Android 7.0. Has anyone faced with some similar issue? The log is pointing to SemClipboardManager line 1326.
This is the log

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: super.getSystemService(name) must not be null
at com.myclubhub.app.screens.ActivityBase.getSystemService(ActivityBase.kt:41)
at com.samsung.android.content.clipboard.SemClipboardManager.isCocktailBarDisplayed(SemClipboardManager.java:1326)
at com.samsung.android.content.clipboard.SemClipboardManager.clearFilter(SemClipboardManager.java:947)
```

In ActivityBase I am just overriding getSystemService.

The issue is that I don't posses Samsung device running Android 7.0, so it's hard for me to debug the app. I do thing that for some reason context is null and probably when activity is trying to call Layoutinflater service is getting null.

Comment: Seems to be a common issue: https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/740

Comment: yeah, I saw the thread - I am wondering how could Samsung allow this kind of issue ti slip over. Is there a way to handle this kind of error, at least I could be able to pop up a dialog to user saying that device is not supported?